# get the roles previously linked to users

Tags: react-admin

i have a problem i cannot solve, and i think im following the documentation to the letter.

I want to obtain the assigned roles when im editing the user, for example if exist a user "Daniel", which has "Administrator" and "Editor" roles. When im editing that user i would like to obtain those assigned roles.

my code is:

> ```
> export const UserEdit = props => (
> <Edit title={<RoleTitle />} {...props}>
>     <SimpleForm validate={validateUserEdition}>
>         <TextInput source="name" />
>         <TextInput source="email" type="email" />
>         <TextInput source="password" type="password" />
>         <ReferenceInput label="Role" source="role" reference="role">
>             <AutocompleteArrayInput source="id" {...props} />
>         </ReferenceInput>
>     </SimpleForm>
> </Edit>
> );
> ```

Add the endpoint format where check my API:

GET to /user/{user}/role

someone help me with this please?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what the `react-admin` say:

> **You must add a  for the reference resource - react-admin needs it to fetch the reference data.**

So in your case, the `<Admin/>` component should at least have these:

```js
<Admin dataProvider={myDataProvider}>
  <Resource name="users" /> // endpoint that handles user records
  <Resource name="roles" /> // endpoint that handles user ROLES records
</Admin>
```

Am not sure how you are using this endpoint `/user/{user}/role` but it clearly will not do what you want. [Further reading here should help](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html) especially look at the **notes** added to the `Reference*` components.

Comment: Hello, I still cannot solve my problem, the resources that I have in my administrator are user and role, but I imagine that with those resources they are enough to have the relationship between the two.

my code is the follow 

app.js
const App = ( ) => (
    <Admin dashboard={ Dashboard } dataProvider={ dataProvider } authProvider={ authProvider }>
        <Resource name="user" list={ UserList } create={ UserCreate } edit={ UserEdit } icon={ UserIcon }/>
        <Resource name="role" list={ RoleList } create={ RoleCreate } edit={ RoleEdit } icon={ ContactsIcon }/>
   </Admin>
);

Answer (score 0):

I still cannot solve my problem, the resources that I have in my administrator are user and role, but I imagine that with those resources they are enough to have the relationship between the two.

Again, when I edit a user, I need to be able to view and edit the roles associated with it.

my code is the follow

```
export const UserEdit = props => (
<Edit title={<RoleTitle />} {...props}>
    <SimpleForm validate={validateUserEdition}>
        <TextInput source="name" />
        <TextInput source="email" type="email" />
        <TextInput source="password" type="password" />
        <ReferenceInput label="Role" source="role" reference="role">
            <AutocompleteArrayInput source="id" {...props} />
        </ReferenceInput>
    </SimpleForm>
</Edit>
);
```

in app.js

```
const App = ( ) => (
    <Admin dashboard={ Dashboard } dataProvider={ dataProvider } authProvider={ authProvider }>
        <Resource name="user" list={ UserList } create={ UserCreate } edit={ UserEdit } icon={ UserIcon }/>
        <Resource name="role" list={ RoleList } create={ RoleCreate } edit={ RoleEdit } icon={ ContactsIcon }/>
   </Admin>
);
```

Thank

Comment: Hey, it's important that we don't assume a relationship between these two. How is your data from the backend? Does the User object actually have a "roles" field in it?